# In jquery "find" function returns results, while "filter" doesn't

Tags: jquery, filter, find

If to follow by documentation, it seems that "filter" should return more results that "find" function.
But it's not working as expected:

```
$(content).find('#conversationTable').length 
1
```

while

```
$(content).filter('#conversationTable').length
0
```

Comment: remember...filter filters results from an element collection, whereas find finds results from an element (searching with the element as the parent).

Answer (score 0):

`filter` only applies *to the items in the jQuery object/collection itself* and *not* its descendants.

`find` looks deeper down the hierarchy (but not at the level of the jQuery collection it is applied to). It *only searches descendants*.

*In practice you use `filter` to reduce a set of elements, based on some additional criteria. `find` is a general "search from a given starting point(s)"*